# If a smoky potion is diluted, does it still have the same chance of producing a djinni as an undiluted smoky potion?

Tags: nethack

I have an opportunity to make quite a few smoky potions (in this case, booze) through alchemy, but I know that alchemy produces diluted potions. I also know that a diluted potion still has the same effect as undiluted. Still, the wiki says nothing about  dilution affecting the chances of producing a djinni (or, a ghost in the case of milky potions). I'd hate waste all the potential holy waters by converting and drinking them if they wont work, but I have enough to work the odds, IF they still have the same potential.
 I could use up to 6 charges in my polymorph wand, but that has such a high degree of of randomness that I would rather save them for bigger piles of items I've yet to accumulate. So, is it worth the effort, or are diluted potions somehow incapable of producing djinn ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the dilution status has no effect at all on how the potion works, with the exception of booze and fruit juice giving less nutrition. Alchemizing potions to get smoky to quaff for wishes is just as effective as actually finding the undiluted smoky potions.